# c:\windows\system32\dns deleting .dns file

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, dns, system32

I'm having trouble deleting zone files using scripts from

`c:\windows\system32\dns`

If I delete using a vbscript, the zone is removed from the DNS server, but the zone file (.dns) remains with Windows saying "The system cannot find the file specified". I have tried this using powershell and ASP.net, but all with the same result.

However, if I try directly from the command line on the console, it works fine, so something appears to be 'hiding' the files in `c:\windows\system32\dns` to prevent script access, but I don't know what. Anyone else seen this and have ideas?

It's Windows 2012 R2.

```
Dim ObjExecutor : Set ObjExecutor = CreateObject("ASPExec.Execute")

ObjExecutor.Application = "dnscmd localhost /ZoneDelete domain.com /f"
ObjExecutor.ExecuteDosApp 

ObjExecutor.Application = "cmd /c del c:\windows\system32\dns\domain.com.dns"
ObjExecutor.ExecuteDosApp 

set ObjExecutor  = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Remove-DnsServerZone from Domain Name System (DNS) Server PowerShell Cmdlets [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161221070445/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649850.aspx). I've used them before and they've worked wonderfully for me.

Comment: That removes the DNS zone, it doesn't remove the .dns file, however.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this, it's because of 32 bit requests redirecting to the syswow64 folder, so I had to change the site to compile into 64-bit, and it worked fine.